# Post JSON request in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

I need to post JSON data that looks like this :

```
 { “orders”:[ {“id”: 208, “quantity”: 1 },{“id”: 212, “quantity”: 2},{“id”: 202, “quantity”: 5}, ...etc  ],“HHStatus”: “1 }
```

I have the following variable :

```
var orders : [ShoppingCart] = []
```

that contains data as :

[Crash.ShoppingCart(drinkId: 743, drinkName: "aqua", drinkPrice: "2.26", drinkQuantity: 2), Crash.ShoppingCart(drinkId: 715, drinkName: "yellow", drinkPrice: "6.92", drinkQuantity: 1), Crash.ShoppingCart(drinkId: 738, drinkName: "blue", drinkPrice: "4.69", drinkQuantity: 2)]

...etc

I am able to post the request using :

```
for order in orders {
        let orderId = order.drinkId
        let orderQuantity = order.drinkQuantity

    let parameters = ["orders": [["id": orderId, "quantity": orderQuantity]], "HHStatus": orderHHStatus!] as [String : Any]

    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

but then I want the whole order not just one id and one quantity,

and I have tried using :

```
    let orderId = orders.map { $0.drinkId }
    let orderQuantity = orders.map { $0.drinkQuantity }

    let parameters = ["orders": [["id": orderId, "quantity": orderQuantity]], "HHStatus": orderHHStatus!] as [String : Any]

    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

but then I end up with something like this :

```
["HHStatus": "0", "orders": [["id": [743, 715, 738], "quantity": [2, 1, 2]]]]
```

How can I send all the ids and quantities in one request?

I can't figure out how to get something like :

```
["orders": [["id": orderId, "quantity": orderQuantity],["id": orderId, "quantity": orderQuantity], ["id": orderId, "quantity": orderQuantity]], "HHStatus": orderHHStatus!]
```

so many thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Map the `ShoppingCart` array to an array of dictionaries with the `map` function:

  ```
  let mappedOrders = orders.map { ["id" : $0.drinkId, "quantity" : $0.drinkQuantity] }
  ```
- Create the `parameters` dictionary

  ```
  let parameters : [String:Any] =  ["orders" : mappedOrders, "HHStatus" : orderHHStatus!]
  ```

Don't pass the `.prettyPrinted` option, the server doesn't care about aesthetics.
Omit the `options` parameter.